# I can't get the IP address of the user

Tags: php

this is probably the last question I ask, I couldn't find the issue... so this is the code that I use:

```
function get_client_ip() {
        $ipaddress = '';
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
        else if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
            $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        else
            $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
        return $ipaddress;
    }
```

And this is what I used to try and see if it picks my IP:

```
<p>IP: <?php get_client_ip(); ?> </p>
```

all I see when I go on the page is IP:
and there is no IP...
I really don't know why this happens...

Comment: can you add `print_r($_SERVER);`

Comment: You need to echo the result, e.g. `<?php echo get_client_ip(); ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not outputting the result of the function. Add `echo` or `print`:

```
<p>IP: <?php echo get_client_ip(); ?> </p>
```

Without that, you're calling the function but not doing anything with the return value.

Comment: Oh well... I did such a silly mistake which costed me a ban on stackoverflow lmao..

Comment: @Andrei Why wasn't this answer, which is more detailed, selected?

Comment: @chris85 It was a hard decision which to select indeed, I tried both, I also tried to upvote both, so I decided to select the first answer...

Answer (score 0):

You need to echo the result of the function

```
<?php echo get_client_ip(); ?>
```